# Add items of different type into list in .Net

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to add items into list (items are of different types). Here is how I'm doing it.

```
 private List<JiraIssues> GetIssues(string result)
    {
        string x = null;
        var summary = x;
        List<JiraIssues> returnResulttoReport = new List<JiraIssues>();
        RootObject myresult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(result);
        foreach (var item in myresult.issues)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.fields.summary);
           summary = item.fields.summary;
            foreach (var commentitem in item.fields.comment.comments)
            {
                var authorname = commentitem.author.name;
                Console.WriteLine(commentitem.author.name);
            }

        }

        /*var vnlist = (from up in spcall
                      where up.Caption == "Contacted"
                      select new JiraIssues
                      {
                          summary,
                          authorname,
                          ActualDate,
                          Value = up.Value
                      }).ToList();*/
        returnResulttoReport.AddRange(summary,authorname);
        return returnResulttoReport ; 
    }
```

Getting error  as;

> AddRange can not take 2 arguments.

For better visibility I'm putting my JiraIssues here:

```
[DataContract]
public class JiraIssues
{
    public JiraIssues()
    {
        Comments = new List<JiraComment>();
        //Components = new List<JiraComponent>();
    }

    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string IssueKey;

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string Id;

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string Description;

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string Assignee;

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public DateTime? Created;

    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public DateTime? Duedate;

    [DataMember(Order = 6)]
    public string Environment;

    [DataMember(Order = 7)]
    public string Priority;

    [DataMember(Order = 8)]
    public string Project;

    [DataMember(Order = 9)]
    public string Reporter;

    [DataMember(Order = 10)]
    public string Resolution;

    [DataMember(Order = 11)]
    public string Status;

    [DataMember(Order = 12)]
    public string Summary;

    [DataMember(Order = 13)]
    public string IssueType;

    [DataMember(Order = 14)]
    public DateTime? Updated;

    [DataMember(Order = 15)]
    public long? Votes;

    [DataMember(Order = 16)]
    public string Components;

    [DataMember(Order = 17)]
    public List<JiraComment> Comments;
}

[DataContract]
public class JiraComment
{
    [DataMember(Order = 0)]
    public string CommentBody;

    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public string CommentAuthor;

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public DateTime? CommentCreated;

    [DataMember(Order = 3)]
    public string CommentUpdateAuthor;

    [DataMember(Order = 4)]
    public DateTime? CommentUpdated;

    [DataMember(Order = 5)]
    public string CommentId;

    [DataMember(Order = 6)]
    public string CommentGroupLevel;

    [DataMember(Order = 7)]
    public string CommentParentKeyId;

    [DataMember(Order = 8)]
    public string CommentParentId;
}
```

How can I slove do this? I need to add and return all the strings from method.

Comment: Are `Summary` and `AuthorName` type compatible with `JiraIssues` at all?

Comment: Documentation of [`List<T>.AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is clear in my opinion. How about adding them with to different `AddRange` instead? But your `summary` _already_ looks like `string`. Consider to change your logic instead. It is not clear what you try to do.

Comment: You've declared returnResulttoReport as a List of JiraIssues.  The only type you can add to that list is JiraIssues.  The AddRange() method is just like the Add() method except it adds a list of JiraIssues to the list.

Comment: Yes.However, the list is having different types of variables.

Comment: How do you plan on it having different types of variables when it's pretty clear you specify `JiraIssues`?

Comment: Just to clear, I have updated my question.PL have look and suggest.Do not downgrade this please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues. First, the call to [`AddRange`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). That takes an enumerable, like an array:

```
returnResulttoReport.AddRange(new string[] { summary, authorname });
```

Second and most importantly, the type of the list, `List<JiraIssues>`, is incompatible with the items you add (of type `string`). You can't do that. That means the above code won't work... You *can* change the type of the list to `List<object>`, but that will make it not strongly-typed and I don't recommend to do that.

Instead, you should find a way to convert the string to a `JiraIssues` instance, or maybe put it in a list of another type.

Let's assume `JiraIssues` has a `Summary` and `Assignee` property, then you could do:

```
returnResulttoReport.Add(new JiraIssues() { Summary = summary, Assignee = authorname });
```

Comment: If some users feel so, some users feel so. Don't be too worried about it.